# How to do joins on temporal tables created using WITH AS in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

I am working in BigQuery and I am using the WITH AS sentence to create temporal tables and then do joins between them, let's name them table_1 and table_2. These tables are complex to create, I mean, they require a lot of work and code, and I need to use them repeatedly and I want to avoid doing big and expensive sub-queries every time, for example, to do left join between them. The thing is when I create table_1 everything is okay, but when I create table_2 and I try to do the left join, a warning pops and tells me that table_1 does not exist, so how can I do this? My code is the following:

```sql
WITH table_1 AS ( SELECT key,f2,f3 FROM xxxxxxx WHERE XXXXXXXXX)
SELECT * table_1;

WITH table_2 AS ( SELECT key,f4,f5 FROM xxxxxxx WHERE XXXXXXXXX)
SELECT * table_2;
```

I want to do a left join between table_1 and table_2 on key, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any hint? thanks in advance and greetings

Comment: Use `WITH` once, but define multiple `common table expressions` inside that single `WITH`.

Comment: Thanks, Paul you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple expressions with `WITH` in the same statement to do your join.

```
WITH table_1 AS ( SELECT key,f2,f3 FROM xxxxxxx WHERE XXXXXXXXX),
table_2 AS ( SELECT key,f4,f5 FROM xxxxxxx WHERE XXXXXXXXX)
SELECT * table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.key = table_2.key;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've done what you said and it's the right way to do what I wanted, greetings